# 音源が取り込めません

Tags: unity3d

音源を取り込もうとしたら
FSBTool.exeがクラッシュしてしまい
音源を取り込むことが出来ません

作業環境は
windows vista sp2

Unityバージョンは5.1.0f3です

対処法を教えてください

Comment: マルチポストですね。 http://okwave.jp/qa/q9119276.html

Answer (score 2):

[動作環境](https://unity3d.com/jp/unity/system-requirements)を見るとWindows Vistaには対応していないと明記されています。